# Validation & External APIs - Rescue in Controller or Fatten Model validations?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, faraday

I am using [Restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) to query records from a remote salesforce instance. The user simply has to put in a valid UID for the record they want to query.

Restforce uses [Faraday middleware](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday) to deal with http requests - and raises a `Faraday::ResourceNotFound` error if I request something that cannot be located in the remote salesforce database.

**Question**

Where should I validate user input?

I have two ideas but i'm not sure of the consequences to each... and I'm trying to work out how to stick best to the fat model - skinny controller best practice.

**Check for successful query at the application controller level**

Requests save the UID to a simple ActiveRecord model `@record_request`. My create method can fire a query, check for an error and flash/redirect the user if needed.

```
  # app/controllers/record_requests_controller
  def create
    @record_request = current_user.record_requests.new(record_request_params)
    
    # Check to see if CHAIN number exists
    if @record_request.restforce.find("Contact", @record_request.chain_number, 'ClientID__c')

      # If it gets past that do standard validation checks
      if @record_request.save
        flash[:success] = 'Record request was successfully created.'
        redirect_to record_requests_path
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
```

Then over in the ApplicationController I've got a rescue method setup

```
 # app/controllers/application_controller
  rescue_from Faraday::ResourceNotFound, with: :resource_not_found

  private

    def resource_not_found
        flash[:alert] = 'Cannot find resource on Salesforce'
        redirect_to(:back)
    end
```

This works! And seems fine... but...

**Model level validation?**

My gut tells me this is a validation and should be validated on the model level, what if there's a bug and something sneaks into my database? Should this all just be checked at the `if @record_request.save` moment?

If so... how would i get model level code to handle validation AND be able to fire off an external (OAuth authenticated) API request without breaking the MVC.

What are the implications to either, and how might I do better?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to use model level validation something like this:

```
validate :something

def something
  errors.add(:field, 'error message') unless RestClient.check_something
end
```

Where RestClient is singleton object in /lib folder. This will allow to keep controller clean.